# Validation of email field text box in MVC

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a window which looks like this -

[image]

Whenever i click on '+' it adds a row below like this -

[image]

and '-' deletes the row.

As you can see the field is not validated and it adds the row even if nothing is entered. The code which I have written is distributed in two files.

**InviteUser.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddUser", "ManageUsers", new { area = "AccountAdmin" }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnFailure = "onCallFailure(data);", OnSuccess = "onCallSuccess(data);", UpdateTargetId = "inviteUserContainer" }, new { id = "form1" }))
{
    <div id="items">
        @{
            if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("inviteUserEditor", item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Html.RenderAction("BlankInviteUserEditor", "ManageUsers", new { area = "AccountAdmin" });
            }
        }
    </div>
```

This file runs the loop and

**InviteUSerEditor.cshtml**

```
<div class="rowcontainer7">
<input type="hidden" name="@(ViewData["prefix"] + ".index" )" value="@(model.Id )" />
@Html.Hidden((string)(fieldPrefix + "Id"), (int)ViewData.Model.Id)



@Html.TextBox(((string)fieldPrefix + "Email"), (string)ViewData.Model.Email, new { @class = "form-control vsminput3 " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Message) ? "" : "input-validation-error"), placeholder ="Email" })

@Html.DropDownList((string)(fieldPrefix + "GroupId"), model.Groups.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.GroupName, Selected = (model.GroupId == x.Id) }),"--Select Group--", new { @class = "form-control vsmselect3 vsminline2" })


<a href="#" class="removeRow btn btn-blue btn_inline" role="button" onclick="deleteContainer(event)"> -</a>
```

This has the basic structure of textbox and drop - down. 
Although, I gave it a try to validate the field, I wasn't successful. If the '+' is clicked it should not add a row and the textbox and drop down menu should be turned red with some popover message if nothing is entered or selected.

Another thing to mention is there is no model for this textbox created. Hence, I have to do the validation on client side itself. I am struggling on this from quite some time now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to jQuery in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

you have two options for this, client side and server side validation

client side

```
$('#plusButtonId').on('click', function() {
 if ($('#inputId').val() == '') {
  //display error message etc..
 } else {
  //add new row
 }
});
```

server side could simply be a check to see if the model state is valid

```
//for server side to kick in, you would need to be hitting the server
//i.e doing an ajax call to load a new row
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
 //handle the request
}
```

Comment: You have two options, and you should go with BOTH of them. Client Side only validation is not a good idea!

Comment: I completely disagree with this. You should do both types of validation not just client side. Pleas do BOTH! Check in your action method to make sure the model state is valid.